# Can a Prime Ideal be equal to the parent Ring?

Tags: ring-theory

If $I$ is a prime ideal of $R$, can $I=R$?

Answer (score 6):

No. By definition, a prime ideal is a proper ideal, meaning that it is not the entire ring. This is mostly because there are theorems about prime ideals that don't work for the entire ring, and so it's easier to assert that prime ideals are not the whole ring than to put a "Let $I$ be a prime ideal of $R$ which is not equal to the whole ring" in many theorems and proofs.

Comment: Thank u so much @Stella Biderman , for clearing my doubt. This question came in mind coz in many standard books I've come across, they never mentioned that a prime ideal is a proper ideal.

Comment: @Heisnam I have read a great deal of ring theory books, and *all* of them specify that a prime ideal must be proper.